# react native mms dont send attachment

Tags: reactjs, native, mms

I am using expo-sms in Android Reactnative.  This is my Code:

```
if (isAvailable) {
  const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync( '123456789', 'Hello World MMS', {
        attachments:{
          uri: path, //path string is type content://
          mimeType: 'image/png',
          filename: mFile,
        },
    }
  );
```

The system send "Hello World MMS" but don't sent attachment.